# .net 7 Disable middleware for a specific endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, webapi, .net-7.0

It is possible to disable middleware for a specific endpoint? I have middleware which is registered in app using:

```
app.UseMiddleware<SomeMiddleware>(someArgs);
```

I want to use this middleware in all methods, except login() and refresh(). Is there any attribute that can be used to mark a method? I don't want to make a condition on `context.Request.Path.

Comment: If you're ok intercepting after routing, you can use a custom controller factory to handle this. If you want something prior to routing, then the middleware with a condition will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to make a condition on `context.Request.Path`. Then I recommended to create a custom `Attribute` to implement this.

*SkipMyMiddlewareAttribute.cs*

```
namespace ASPNETCORE_MVC
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class SkipMyMiddlewareAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

}
```

**MyMiddleware.cs**

```
namespace ASPNETCORE_MVC
{
    public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
            if (endpoint != null)
            {
                // Check if the endpoint has the [SkipMiddleware] attribute
                var skip = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<SkipMyMiddlewareAttribute>();
                if (skip == null)
                {
                    // Middleware logic here...
                }
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }

}
```

*Register it*

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

*How to use it ? You can add it in controller or specific methods*

[image]

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Can I Check in the same way if method have [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] ?

Comment: Hi @blane, Sure, [something like this](https://codeshare.io/78qxLL) .

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MapWhen` or `UseWhen`.

See [Branch the middleware pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline):

```
app.UseWhen(
predicate: context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWith..., 
configuration: builder =>
{
   builder.UseMiddleware<SomeMiddleware>(someArgs);
});
```